# Python: Pythonic way to import all variables with a specific identifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I want to neatly import all variables in a file that have '_COLUMN' in their name. I do this because there are 20+ variables and the *normal* import statement would be huge. I also want the variables to be directly accessible e.g. `TIME_COLUMN` and not `earthquakes.tools.TIME_COLUMN`

The following code works:

```
import earthquakes.tools    
for item in dir(earthquakes.tools):
    if '_COLUMN' in item:
        exec(f'from earthquakes.tools import {item}')
```

Is this considered Pythonic ? If not, is there *a better way* or should this not even be done ?

For information, I have tried searching for regex in import statements and other solutions but did not find anything significant.

Please do not mention `from ... import *` as it is not considered Pythonic

Comment: Doesn't `import earthquakes.tools` already import all of them?

Comment: Mandatory reading https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html and http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html Most likely it will be better to use a dict instead of individual names.

Comment: `foo_COLUMN = earthquake.tools.foo_COLUMN` for each relevant `foo`. Querying with `dir` doesn't make a lot of sense, because if you don't know what columns already exist, you won't know what variables your loop makes available anyway.

Comment: @ScottHunter it does but I would like them to be directly accessible. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @chepner even if there are 20+ variables and the number is likely to grow?

Comment: If there are that many variables, and you are in control of `earthquake.tools`, then see [buran's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558046/python-pythonic-way-to-import-all-variables-with-a-specific-identifier?noredirect=1#comment124727164_70558046). If you aren't in control of the module, I would suggest building your *own* `dict` using `getattr`; my comment about using `dir` to define a bunch of unknown variables stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `_COLUMN`-prefixed variables should probably be a `dict` in the first place, but if you can't do that in `earthquake.tools` yourself, you can build a local one using `getattr`.

```
import earthquake.tools


column_names = ["foo", "bar", "baz", ...]

columns = {k: getattr(earthquake.tools, f'{k}_COLUMN') for k in column_names}
```

Don't use `dir` to "infer" the columns names. No one reading the scipt will know what variables are defined without knowing what `earthquake.tools` defines in the first place, so be explicit and list the names you *expect* to be using. (There is no point creating a variable you will never actually use.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this trick

```
from earthquakes.tools import *
```

Comment: I believe this is not considered very Pythonic

Comment: True, but since calling all variables of a module is not that paythonic, so it would be hard to give a very paythonic solution...correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `__all__` variable of the module:

`tools.py`

```
__all__ == ['var1_COLUMN', 'var2_COLUMN', 'var3_COLUMN']
```

`main.py`:

```
from earthquakes.tools import *
```

To know more: [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

Comment: I feel like this is somehow hacky and not very Pythonic ? Wouldn't it also mean editing `__all__` every time a variable is added or removed ?

Comment: You can buid dynamically your variable inside your module.